# How to match line of csv which is ignored by constraint and create only relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

I have been created a graph having a constraint on primary id. In my csv a primary id is duplicate but the other proprieties are different. Based on the other properties I want to create relationships.

I tried multiple times to change the code but it does not do what I need.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Trial.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'  
MATCH (n:Trial {id: line.primary_id})  
with line.cui= cui 
MATCH (m:Intervention) 
where m.id = cui 
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_INTERVENTION]->(m);
```

I already have the nodes Intervention in the graph as well as the trials. So what I am trying to do is to match a trial with the id from intervention and create only the relationship. Instead is creating me also the nodes.

This is a sample of my data, so the same primary id, having different cuis and I am trying to match on cui:

[image: This is a sample of my data, so the same primary id, having different cuis and I am trying to match on cui.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the following query which finds Trial and Intervention nodes by primary_id and cui respectively and creates the relationship between them.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Trial.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'  
MATCH (n:Trial {id: line.primary_id}), (m:Intervention {id: line.cui})
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_INTERVENTION]->(m);
```

Comment: if I change the MERGE to CREATE, is it still going to do what I want? I would like to create also duplicate relationships. From what I know if I change that it will create me all relationships including duplicates.

Comment: I want to make the graph weighted based on duplicate relationships between the nodes

Comment: Yeah, it will work. and It will create multiple relationships. Don't forget to delete the relationships created by merge query otherwise, there will be one extra relationship between each pair.

Comment: perfect! Thank you for the support

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you observed is caused by 2 aspects of the Cypher language:

1. The [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/with/) clause *drops all existing variables* except for the ones explicitly specified in the clause. Therefore, since your `WITH` clause does not specify the `n` node, `n` becomes an unbound variable after the clause.
2. The [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/merge/) clause will create its *entire pattern* if any part of the pattern does not already exist. Since `n` is not bound to anything, the `MERGE` clause would go ahead and create the entire pattern (including the 2 nodes).

So, you could have fixed the issue by simply specifying the `n` variable in the `WITH` clause, as in:

```
WITH n, line.cui= cui
```

But @Raj's query is even better, avoiding the need for `WITH` entirely.